# How to hide this list item using CSS

Tags: html, css

How to hide the "Discussion" item from the list?

```
<div id="psp-primary-header" class="psp-grid-row cf">
<nav class="nav psp-masthead-nav" id="psp-main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="nav-menu"><a href="#" class="">Menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="nav-milestones"><a href="#psp-phases" class="">Phases</a> </li>
                <li id="nav-talk"><a href="#psp-discussion" class="">Discussion</a> </li>
                <li id="nav-logout"><a href="https://www.google.com">Logout</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
#nav-talk {display:none !important};
```

Comment: That should work... Can you prove it doesn't? `:P` And make sure the `id` is not duplicated or used elsewhere. Hey, you have a `;` after the `}` making it invalid, may be.

Comment: Is that the only place where that id is?

Comment: where do you put your CSS, if it's in external file dont forget to import it in your html file

Comment: Use Devtools (f12) in your your browser if choice and inspect the list item. See what classes are applied and what is being overwritten. You will also see if there is a more specific rule in place.

Comment: The id isn't used anywhere else, fixed the `;` but still doesn't work. It's a wordpress page and there's a option to insert custom CSS. I've used another line of css which works but this doesn't.

Comment: On a side note be very cautious about using `!important` : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) issue.

Try

```
#psp-primary-header > #psp-main-nav > #nav-talk {display:none;}
```

Then remove the parent IDs one at a time to find where the specificity conflict is.

For example, if you were to also have:

```
.nav #nav-menu li {display:inline-block !important;}
```

That would be applied over:

```
#nav-talk {display:none !important;}
```

With `#nav-talk` having `display:inline-block`

See the difference between [Id](https://jsfiddle.net/b74hesas/) vs [More Specific](https://jsfiddle.net/b74hesas/1/)

Comment: The first css didn't work.After making it inline and then hiding it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the external CSS doesn't work, as you state in your question, you could write it into the HTLM of that line:

```
<li id="nav-talk" style="display:none;"><a href="#psp-discussion" class="">Discussion</a> </li>
```